# Is it possible to delete the private id of a video at Dailymotion?

Tags: dailymotion-api

A different private id is genererated on each request (regarding the api documentation). Is it possible to delete the old private ids?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to delete the private ID of a video on Dailymotion.